# Jquery tabs use absolute position instead of display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

Jquery's tabs work by setting the nonactive tabs to be "display:none". My question is, is there a way to make it display off the screen (through perhaps absolute) away, say, -999999 pixels from the screen rather than having it be display:none? I have an application that resets whenever the division's width/height are changed, which means that the application is reset each time when the display is set to none.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a right approach to set it -999999px. Better question is: why does your application reset after each change?

Comment: I'm utilizing cytoscape.js and it was mentioned to me that it resets on display:none. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740269/initializing-cytoscape

Comment: @HenriS. Do you think that the better way to approach this problem is to ensure that the program does not redraw the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to stop SWF inside of a jQuery UI tab from reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610976/how-to-stop-swf-inside-of-a-jquery-ui-tab-from-reloading)

This solved my question perfectly. Make sure to use tab-panels as suggested.